# Pyramid returns new session

Tags: python, session, pyramid, cornice

I use Cornice to make RESTful urls.

I installed pyramid-beaker and added the include to my `__init__.py` as specified in the doc.

That's it. Then I did this in my views:

```
p_desc = """Service to post session. """
p = Service(name='p',\
                    path=root+'/1',\
                    description=register_desc)
g_desc = """Service to get session. """
g = Service(name='g',\
                    path=root+'/2',\
                    description=g_desc)

@g.get()
def view2(request):
    print request.session
    return Response()

@p.post()
def view1(request):
    print 'here'
    request.session['lol'] = 'what'
    request.session.save()
    print request.session
    return Response()
```

And this is my outcome

```
>>> requests.post('http://localhost/proj/1')
<Response [200]>
>>> requests.get('http://localhost/proj/2')
<Response [200]>

Starting HTTP server on http://0.0.0.0:6543
here
{'_accessed_time': 1346107789.2590189, 'lol': 'what', '_creation_time': 1346107789.2590189}
localhost - - [27/Aug/2012 18:49:49] "POST /proj/1 HTTP/1.0" 200 0

{'_accessed_time': 1346107791.0883319, '_creation_time': 1346107791.0883319}
localhost - - [27/Aug/2012 18:49:51] "GET /proj/2 HTTP/1.0" 200 4
```

As you can see it gives back new session. How do I get that same session so that I can access that same data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sessions are tracked with a cookie sent to the client. So your 'client' (the `requests` library) needs to actually send that cookie back again:

```
resp = requests.post('http://localhost/proj/1')
cookies = resp.cookies

requests.get('http://localhost/proj/2', cookies=cookies)
```

Better still would be to use a [`requests.Session` set-up](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects):

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post('http://localhost/proj/1')
    s.get('http://localhost/proj/2')
```

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate [@Martijn Pieters's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12150748/4279):

```
import requests

def t(r, url="http://httpbin.org/cookies"): 
    print(r.get(url).json['cookies'])

with requests.session() as s:
    t(requests)             # request without session
    t(s)                    # request within session
    t(s, "http://httpbin.org/cookies/set?name=value")  # set cookie
    t(requests)             # request without session
    t(s)                    # request within session
```

#### Output

```
{}                  # request without session
{}                  # request within session
{u'name': u'value'} # set cookie
{}                  # request without session
{u'name': u'value'} # request within session
```